# Google Map API V2 in Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I want to use Google Maps in Fragment to show current location of user but before that I wanted just to show map. When I tested I have error as in the picture. What the best way to add Google Map API V2 and whats the reason to error?

**fragment.xml**

```
<fragment
         android:id="@+id/googleMap"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**Fragment.java**

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       GoogleMap mGoogleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap)).getMap();
}
```

**Manifect file:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="www.smartavenue.com.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>

<!--meta-data is in the application-->
<meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

 <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
       android:value="My key"/>
```

In **build.gramble** I added: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'`

**Error**:
[image]

Comment: Please try [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ADb5bNOFHE) step by step, you will get the `google map` show on the Android

Comment: @bjiang hello! Thanks for this sourse but it work with Activity and I need Fragment. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @bjiang I tried now to test it with ActionBarActivity and I have the same error as in the picture. That the reason of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :
 [Google Map API V2 Demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wls4kbafkwmf7mf/GoogleMap.rar?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line :

> Multiple dex file define Lcome/google/ads/Adrequest

you have two library in your gradle file which both use AdRequest library
In your gradle file, check and clean the conflict libraries.

try building with --debug or --stacktrace to see the exact libraries which have conflicts